# Aligning graphs in R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am working on creating a dashboard, so far everything has worked except for the display, ideally I would like my five graphs to be displayed next to each other, three on top and two at the bottom. they however are displayed one below the other. Can I realign them? The ui.R code is as follows:

```
     mainPanel(

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Items", plotOutput("phonePlot"),plotOutput("phonePlot2"),
               plotOutput("phonePlot3"),plotOutput("phonePlot4"),plotOutput("phonePlot5")), 
      tabPanel("Ethnicity", plotOutput("demo1"),plotOutput("demo2")),
      tabPanel("Income Group", plotOutput("Income1"),plotOutput("Income2")),
      tabPanel("Household Size", plotOutput("House1"),plotOutput("House2")),
      tabPanel("Children Group", plotOutput("child1"),plotOutput("child2")),
      tabPanel("Self Improvement", plotOutput("improve1"),plotOutput("improve2"))
      )
```

Comment: By specifying  `column` you can I think. Perhaps, you can take a look at that.

Comment: See the bits about columns at the bottom [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html).